# Which Aloe Vera plant has the most healing property?

Tags: plant-recommendations, aloe

I look for the Aloe Vera plant(s) for [exercise-induced (EI) hypersensitivity](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29743/increasing-prevalence-of-allergies-and-poly-sensitivity-in-athletes-why) such as allergic rhinitis. Which Aloe Vera plants has the most healing property?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the health and nutritional aspects of fruits/vegetables; this is specifically off topic per the help center at http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Ecnerwal thank you for the observation, updated to be more accessible.

Comment: If they're actually wanting to grow the said plant, I would think it applies here. If they just want to know which one without regard to it, than I'd say close it (although it's unfortunate there's not another SE site for that topic).

Comment: I mean, it seems on topic for someone to come and say they're looking to grow a cherry tree, but they want one that meets certain criteria, which may or may not pertain to nutrition and health, sweetness, etc. asking for recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend **Aloe Vera Barbadensis Miller, Stockton variety** on which related

- [Which soil should be used with Aloe Vera Barbadensis Miller, Stockton variety?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24573/which-soil-should-be-used-with-aloe-vera-barbadensis-miller-stockton-variety)

where the stockton variety is the Aloe having the most healing property by the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvMUY6TNrR4&t=18m30s).